# (Python) TypeError with dictionaries

Tags: python, dictionary, typeerror

I am getting a type error for this piece of code.

```
dataTable = {a :1, "data":{b:2, "children":[{c:3, "data":{d:4,e:5, "likes": null, f:6.....} } } }
data = dataTable["data"]["children"]["data"]["likes"]
```

Output:

```
TypeError: string induces must be integers, not str
```

Could anyone work out the problem in my code and explain why? Thanks!

Comment: Are you sure that's accurate? That code would give a slightly different error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because `dataTable["data"]["children"]` is not a dictionary, it is a list:

```
>>> dataTable = {'a' :1, "data":{'b':2, "children":[{'c':3, "data":{'d':4,'e':5, "likes": 'null', 'f':6} }] } }
>>> type(dataTable["data"]["children"])
<type 'list'>
```

If you want a specific item from the list, get it by index:

```
>>> dataTable["data"]["children"][0]['data']['likes']
'null'
```

If you want all children, iterate over the list:

```
>>> for child in dataTable["data"]["children"]:
...     print child['data']['likes']
... 
null
```

Comment: Ah, it worked. Thanks! I guess I need to take a look at dictionaries.

Answer (score 0):

`dataTable["data"]["children"]` is a list, so it makes no sense to query `data` on it.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: @TonyHopkinson It does, you're supposed to query lists with indexes, not with keys.

Comment: Huh? Your "answer" was a comment is all I was saying.